# What is the fastest way to get the list of files recursively contained in a directory?

Tags: linux, filesystems, nfs

I have a directory that contains millions of files spread out in a hierarchy of folders. This directory is stored on a large remote NFS filesystem. I'd like to retrieve the list of these files as fast as possible.

Is it possible to go faster than `find . > list.txt`? What factors affect speed? I'm using python, but any solution will go as long as it's *fast*.

Comment: Unless you stored a file containing the list of all of them, retrieving online the list of millions of files takes time... :)

Comment: @Saphrosit : I know it takes time and I expect it, but I wonder if there is a way to 'ask the filesystem for the data all at once', instead of polling each directory and file.

Comment: ls -r is probably the fastest you can get. there's no way to ask the filesystem for all the data at once. the fact that the data is remote makes things worse. a local implementation would be faster (for example if you could ssh into the server and therefore create the list locally).

Comment: note: at low level `fts` and `ftw` (google or use `man`) are the fastest routines that do it. but a decent implementation of `ls` should either use them or use code that is extremely similar to the one they use. At an even lower level (the real building blocks) you get things like `opendir` (sufficient for the list of filenames if the filesystem supports the `d_type` field in `dirent`) and `(l)stat`.

Comment: @AnalogFile: thanks for your answer! What happens if you decide to forego POSIX compatibility and look at NFS-only functions? Is there any thing there?

Comment: I'm not an NFS expert. But I guess NSF is in fact a file system. Does the low level protocol support anything above the building blocks? No idea. I'd have to google it or look into an implementation source/docs (which I guess you can do yourself). Note that `ls` and `find` can only work at the standard filesystem API level. And even `fts` and `ftw` are implemented in terms of calls to `opendir`, `(l)stat` and do-not-remember-the-name for changing current directory, so I'll be surprised to learn that NFS gives you more. If you find it does post your findings.

Comment: @AnalogFile it's `ls -R` to recurse, `-r` will just reverse the list.

Answer (score 3):

On linux, this was the fastest for me. Use (bash) globbing and printf like this:

```
printf "%s\n" directory/**/file
printf "%s\x00" directory/**/filename-with-special-characters | xargs -0 command
```

Seems to be a lot faster than

```
find directory -name file
```

or

```
ls -1R directory | grep file
```

or even, surprisingly,

```
ls directory/**/file
```

This was a local file system though: x86_64 system, ext4 filesystem on an SSD, in a directory structure of over 600,000 directories with multiple files in them.

Comment: Could you add some numbers, to give an approximate idea?

Comment: Will work if number of files won't go beyond bash command line limit.

Answer (score 0):

Depending what do you want in the output. I recommend using

```
ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'
```

for the complete path to all the files recursively in the current directory.

Comment: I don't understand the sed part but doesn't this only show the directories?

Comment: Yes, it limits the output to only the data you want. Try to run it without the sed part to see the difference: ls -R | grep ":$"